# How to document nested properties in JSDOC in a readable way?

Tags: jsdoc

I'm making my first open source JS plugin for NPM and want to make it well documented.

But the generated documentation of the class constructor looks too large and goes out of my screen. 
[image: looks bad]

```
class Karaoke {

  /**
   * Magic happen here.
   * @constructor
   * @param   {HTMLElement} element  DOM HTML element that used as a Karaoke instance root element.
   * @param   {object}      options  Options for the Karaoke instance.
   * @param   {object[]}    options.tracks An array of tracks for the karaoke.
   * @param   {string}      options.tracks[].url Audio file URL.
   * @param   {string}      options.tracks[].bgImg Background image URL  for the current track.
   * @param   {object[]}    options.tracks[].lyrics An array of a track lyrics lines.
   * @param   {string}      options.tracks[].lyrics[].text The text of the lyrics line.
   * @param   {number}      options.tracks[].lyrics[].start The time in milliseconds when lyrics line playing must to begin.
   * @param   {number}      options.tracks[].lyrics[].duration The lyrics line playing duration in milliseconds.
   * @param   {object[]}    options.tracks[].lyrics[].keyframes An array of keyframes for the lyrics line CSS playing animation.
   * @param   {string}      options.tracks[].lyrics[].keyframes[].key A key for the lyrics line CSS playing animation.
   * @param   {number}      options.tracks[].lyrics[].keyframes[].value A value for lyrics line CSS playing animation.
   */
  constructor( element, options = {} ) {
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is there some way to make it more readable?

Comment: Kudos for documenting your API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage the [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) (type definition) tag

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Keyframe
 * @property {string} key A key for the lyrics line CSS playing animation.
 * @property {number} value A value for lyrics line CSS playing animation.
 */

/**
 * @typedef {object} Lyric
 * @property {string}     text The text of the lyrics line.
 * @property {number}     start The time in milliseconds when lyrics line playing must to begin.
 * @property {number}     duration The lyrics line playing duration in milliseconds.
 * @property {Keyframe[]} keyframes An array of keyframes for the lyrics line CSS playing animation.
 */

/**
 * @typedef {object} Track
 * @property {string}  url An array of tracks for the karaoke.
 * @property {string}  bgImg Background image URL for the current track.
 * @property {Lyric[]} lyrics An array of a track lyrics lines.
 */

 /**
  * @typedef {object} Options
  * @property {Track[]} tracks An array of tracks for the karaoke.
  */

class Karaoke {
  /**
   * Magic happen here.
   * @constructor
   * @param {HTMLElement} element DOM HTML element that used as a Karaoke instance root element.
   * @param {Options}     options Options for the Karaoke instance.
   */
  constructor( element, options = {} ) {
  }
}
```

Which will generate the following HTML documentation:

[image]

When you click on the `Options` link:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will be appreciated if you know any well documented libraries for example %)

Comment: I like the [Ramda documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/) for example